# Exporting feature's geometry coordinates to readable file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geometry, export

I'm new to ArcGIS and I'm am trying to export the coordinates on the bottom to a human-readable file, see example below.

[image: Example]

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: How are you at python? There is an example https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002z0000001t000000 , open a file with open('c:\your\name.txt','w') as TxtFile then in the loop for pnt in part write('{},{}\n'.format(pnt.X,pnt.Y)) to export the coords as text.

Comment: Select all records, right click on left border, copy selected. Paste in Excel, keep table open.